# 22.04 Phantom Mouse movement

Tags: mouse, 22.04

Somewhat related to this: [Mouse pointer moving by itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223311/mouse-pointer-moving-by-itself/1339697) - but there is no "keyboard mouse".

Currently my workstation, with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 (and all updates) is experiencing phantom mouse movement.  This did not happen on 20.04 two weeks ago.
A few days ago, the mouse was connected, it was moving the pointer to the top-left corner, and clicking (bringing up the Cinnamon menu).

Today, *with no mouse connected*, the cursor is moving in a lazy lissajous within a terminal window, occasionally double-clicking.  Desktop is set to "focus follows mouse"; sometimes I see the window loose focus for an absolute split-second, cursor warping about 1000 pixels to the right (to some empty desktop) before returning.

There *was* a mouse connected through a USB hub (along with the keyboard), but I have pulled the whole lot to switch it between computers.  It's been disconnected for some hours.

Is this indicative of a hardware fault?  It's *really* creeping me out.
PC hardware is self-assembled: MSI-mothebroard, Intel i9, 64G RAM, maybe 6 months old.

Comment: I, uh, *might* have found an old mouse plugged into the USB hub, but dangling down behind the desk.  (ー_ー﹡; )

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with Wayland. I have read some forums on this issue as well. I hope your PC has a stick pointer. First I tried disabling the stick pointer.
[Mouse pointer moving by itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223311/mouse-pointer-moving-by-itself.)

If disabling the stick pointer does not work out for you, try changing the custom.conf file in path `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. Uncomment the following line. `#WaylandEnable=false`.
The custom.conf file is read-only. So you may need to use `sudo vim custom.conf` to edit it.
This seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: If you want to disable the stick pointer use the following commands.
`xinput list `
`xinput disable <stick pointer id>`